# NuGet and Visual Studio Toolbox items

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget

NuGet package deployment is very attractive for the following reasons:

- Simplify components update
- Simplify source control of the update files
- Automatic download and installation
- ...

The problem is when the component/library is associated with a Visual Studio Toolbox item. As far as I can see, after getting the latest version of a component, the assembly version goes in conflict with the one of the Toolbox item.

Is there an elegant solution to this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to look at https://bitbucket.org/dfowler/vsixcommands/wiki/Home

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code to install a VSIX extension is the following snippet taken from the [VSIXCommands nuget pacakge](https://bitbucket.org/dfowler/vsixcommands/src/1c4b6bb0f98d29a13d93ffc918f4deb8ab918f06/VsixCommands.psm1?at=default) and should be able to be run from your nuget package installer. Or you could just add a dependency on the [VSIXCommands nuget package](https://bitbucket.org/dfowler/vsixcommands/wiki/Home) directly and use that.

This assumes your controls are packaged as a VSIX extension.

```
$extensionManager = [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package]::GetGlobalService([Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SVsExtensionManager])
$extensionRepository = [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package]::GetGlobalService([Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SVsExtensionRepository])
$VSInstallDir = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0 InstallDir | Select -ExpandProperty InstallDir
$vsixInstallerPath = Join-Path $VSInstallDir VSIXInstaller.exe

function Get-InstalledVsix {
    param(
        [string]
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        $VsixId
    )

    $vsix = $null
    if($extensionManager.TryGetInstalledExtension($VsixId, [ref]$vsix)) {
        $vsix
    }
    else {
        $null
    }
}

function Install-Vsix {
    param(
        [string]
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        $VsixPath
    )

    Start-Process $vsixInstallerPath -ArgumentList $VsixPath -Wait
}
```